# Flex 4.6 TabbedViewNavigator - Remove Border

Tags: apache-flex, tabbar

How to completely remove the button borders of a TabbedViewNavigator in Flex?

I've tried CSS, replacing the skin in AS and MXML with no luck:

[image: tab]
.

I want to create a custom skin to the TabBar, replacing the background image and the labels with icons, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, everything is possible with skins.
TabBar is part of TabbedVieNavigator and also TabBar is inherited from ButtonBar. You should to create skin for ButtonBar and set it for your **TabbedViewNavigator #tabBar** like this:

```
<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    s|TabbedViewNavigator #tabBar
    {
        skinClass: ClassReference("views.skins.TabbedViewNavigatorTabBarSkin");
    }
</fx:Style>
```

where **TabbedViewNavigatorTabBarSkin** is Skin of ButtonBar host component, please look at the screen below:

[image: Creating skin]

Then you just creating you own skins for ButtonBar buttons and set own BG color and icon and other things, which you want. Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom skin with `spark.components.TabbedViewNavigator` as `HostComponent` and define following components to make it work. Now skin your TabBar as u wish. You can add Image instead of Label.

[image]